# How do I solve this limit without L'Hospital's rule?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, limits-without-lhopital

I want to evaluate this limit:
$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\log_4(x+1)-0.5}{x-1}$$

I normally solve similar limits by somehow getting $\ln$ and $(1+x)^{1/x}$ to cancel out, but I don't know what to do here.
I can get it to the form:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\ln(x+2)^{1/x}-\frac{0.5}{x}\ln4$$

but it also isn't of any use because of the $2$ in the left $\ln$ and because of the $x$ that is still left on the right.
So what can I do to solve this? I don't want to use L'Hospital, derivatives or any series expansions.

Comment: Why *don't* you want to use L'Hoptital.

Comment: We are not allowed to use it in our exam.

Comment: @Matthew You can appeal to the definition of a derivative maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\log_{4}{x+1} - 0,5}{x-1}=
\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\log_{4}{x+1} - \log_{4}{2}}{x-1}=
\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\log_{4}{\frac{x+1}{2}}}{x-1}=
\lim_{x \to 0} \log_{4}{(1+\frac{x}{2})^{\frac{1}{x}}}=
\frac{1}{2}\log_{4}e = \frac{1}{2 \ln{4}}$$

Comment: Thank you, this is great!

Answer (score 1):

The limit is a derivative. Consider the function $f(t) = \log_4(t + 1)$. Then $f'(1)$ is, by definition of derivative, equal to
$$
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{f(x) - f(1)}{x-1} = \lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\log_4(x+1) - 0.5}{x-1}
$$
Using chain rules and other derivative tools, we can find this derivative in other ways. As $\log_4(t+1) = \frac{\ln(t+1)}{\ln 4}$, we get
$$
f'(t) = \frac{1}{\ln 4}\frac{1}{t+1}
$$
Now just insert $t = 1$ into this, and you're done.

Comment: L'Hospital in disguise.

Comment: This is nice, but OP didn't want to use derivatives

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Right, I only saw the no-l'Hopital restriction.

Comment: This is the fastest approach if the question is set as multiple choice. Recognizing a complicated limit as a derivative of a complicated function gives us the power of all derivative rules which makes the job trivial. +1

Comment: @YvesDaoust : Also I don't think this makes use of L'Hospital's. In general one can't use L'Hospital's Rule to evaluate a derivative based limit like $\lim_{x\to a} \dfrac{f(x) - f(a)} {x-a} $ as L'Hospital's Rule requires limit of $f'$ to exist which may not always be the case.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: be serious $(f(x)-f(a))/(x-a)\to f'(a)/1$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust:L'Hospital's Rule says that if ratio of derivatives tends to a limit the original ratio also does the same. Applying it here means that if $f$ is continuous at $a$ and $f'(x) \to L$ as $x\to a$ then $(f(x) - f(a)) /(x-a) \to L$. The statement "$(f(x) - f(a)) /(x-a) \to f'(a) $ as $x\to a$" is not a result or a consequence of L'Hospital's Rule but is rather a definition of derivative.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: I don't care about this technicality. The point is that L'Hospital is two derivatives (one of which is trivial), vs. one derivative; in both cases, the differentiations are done analytically, not by explicit limits. The OP said " I don't want to use L'Hospital, derivatives or any series expansions."

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\log_4(x+1) - 0.5}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log_4(x+2) - 0.5}x=\frac12\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log_4(\frac x2+1)}{\frac x2}
\\=\frac1{2\log 4}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(x+1)}x.$$

Now you have a known limit.